# gfortran compiler gives segmentation fault

Tags: macos, fortran, gfortran

I was having trouble running fortran code, so I tried an example code in here:
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.4.0/gfortran/ICHAR.html

```
program read_val
  integer value
  character(len=10) string, string2
  string = '154'

  ! Convert a string to a numeric value
  read (string,'(I10)') value
  print *, value

  ! Convert a value to a formatted string
  write (string2,'(I10)') value
  print *, string2
end program read_val
```

I did

gfortran -o hello3 hello3.f -g3 -fcheck=all -Wall -fbacktrace

And it gave me no warning nor error. However,

./hello3

failed with

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x103eab35c
#1  0x103eaa6f3
#2  0x7fff7376cb5c
#3  0x103fef340
#4  0x103fefd2d
#5  0x103fed78f
#6  0x103ea5cca
#7  0x103ea5e96
Segmentation fault: 11
```

I somehow feel like my gfortran compiler doesn't work properly. I'm not familiar with Mac OS and feel like Xcode/Anaconda/etc messed up my system.

I'm using GNU Fortran (Homebrew GCC 9.3.0_1) 9.3.0, MacOS Mojave 10.14.6.

gfortran path is /usr/local/bin/gfortran
Currently my gfortran is from 'brew install gcc'. I also tried manual download from https://github.com/fxcoudert/gfortran-for-macOS/releases, but it didn't worked either.

Comment: Can you comment out the write statement. I suspect you may be overflowing string2. Although, it should be caught with the fcheck=all. But hey, you never know. Next, I would comment out the read.

Comment: @Tarik When I commented one of them, I still get the SISEGV error. When I commented both, program runs, and I get '1669365499
  f-' (second value changes everytime) But I don't see how that information helps...

Comment: Comment only one at a time to determine the cause.

Comment: @Tarik Sorry if I was not clear. When I comment either one of them, I still get the SIGSESV error, and they look same.

Comment: I always start investigating this way to get closer to the solution. The next thing I would do is increase the length of the strings to 15. It looks like an overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see the code is fine, and it complies and runs correctly on my system

```
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ cat busted.f90 
program read_val
  integer value
  character(len=10) string, string2
  string = '154'

  ! Convert a string to a numeric value
  read (string,'(I10)') value
  print *, value

  ! Convert a value to a formatted string
  write (string2,'(I10)') value
  print *, string2
end program read_val
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ gfortran -std=f2008 -Wall -Wextra -fcheck=all -g busted.f90 
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ ./a.out
         154
        154
```

So as far as I can see your instillation of gfortran is broken. But please always use Implicit None

Comment: I restarted computer and it worked... weird, but thanks for confirming me so I didn't wasted more time fiddling code.